# Post DB users into replica users the Synonyms still point to Source DB users

Tags: oracle, import, synonyms

I have exported users HR,Fin AND imported into new users HR1,FIN1 in the same DB.
The expdb is used for this purpose.The synonyms still point to the source users (HR,FIN)

Example :
Synonym def in Source FIN Schema is 
employee ==> HR.employee.
Post import in FIN Schema the employee synonym still refers to HR.employee instead of HR1.employee

Thanks

Comment: Of course they do. export/import runs the exact same DDL as it was done on the source. So it's not surprising that after restoring the synonym still points to `HR`

Comment: Are you looking for a way to easily modify the synonyms?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe above is the expected behavior of datapump utility for export/import operations. Synonyms, as all other PL/SQL objects are exported as is from the source database schema. When imported to the target database schema the code base remains the same (regardless of external/internal references).

One option would be for you to rebuild the synonyms after import completes. This is a process that can be automated with the use of SQL script. Taking your case as an example we see that we have the below attributes for a synonym:

- *Owner*: The schema name of the synonym owner
- *Synonym* Name: The synonym name
- *Table Owner*: The schema name of the owner for the underlying object that the synonym points to
- *Table Name*: The object name that the synonym is pointing to

In the event that we are importing to a different schema name than the original, we will have to update one or more of the below attributes of a synonym. In your case it should be both as it seems you are changing both the source and the target schema owners.

- *Owner*
- *Table Owner*

The steps should be as below:

1. Export as usual using expdp
2. Create a generation script for the synonyms that need to be rebuild based on the source database schema (* see below example) and execute the script after the export on the source database
3. Import as usual using impdp
4. Execute the generated script to "refresh" the synonyms using the correct references on the target database

**Example**

```
set heading off
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off
set term off
set long 10000
set longchunksize 10000
set linesize 512
set pagesize 1024
set trim on
set trims on
set sqlblanklines off
set serveroutput on
set define on

DEFINE SOURCE_SCHEMA_OWNER=FIN -- Schema owner of the synonym in the source database schema
DEFINE TARGET_SCHEMA_OWNER=FIN1 -- Schema owner of the synonym in the target database schema
DEFINE SOURCE_TABLE_OWNER=HR -- Schema owner of the underlying object
DEFINE TARGET_TABLE_OWNER=HR1 -- Schema owner of the underlying object in the target database schema

spool synonymsRebuild.sql

Select
    'Create Or Replace Synonym '||decode(ds.OWNER,'&&SOURCE_SCHEMA_OWNER','&&TARGET_SCHEMA_OWNER',ds.OWNER)||'.'||
    ds.SYNONYM_NAME||' for '||decode(ds.TABLE_OWNER,'&&SOURCE_TABLE_OWNER', '&&TARGET_TABLE_OWNER', ds.TABLE_OWNER)||'.'||
    ds.TABLE_NAME||';'
From
    dba_synonyms ds Where ds.OWNER IN ('&&SOURCE_SCHEMA_OWNER') and ds.OWNER<>ds.TABLE_OWNER;

spool off
```